# scrollTo function jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I need Jquery's scrollTo function to work for this website: http://cinicraft.com/Silverman/index.html

I've tried the following

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.btnLp3").click(function(){
        $('body,html').scrollTo('#target-examples', 800, {easing:'elasout'});
    });
});
```

And I've tried this too:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.btnLp3").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
    });
});
```

I can't seem to get `scrollTo` working at all.  Does anyone have any ideas? Here's what I have imported:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">  </script>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#wrap2").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WB5qw/)

Comment: I always like to add a bit of offset, gives the viewer some breathing space around the content. Like so `.offset().top - 20}`

Comment: this does not answer the question of why the user is getting the error 'scrollTo is not a function
 ' most will arrive at this question after searching for 'scrollTo is not a function
 ' You don't even use the 'scrollTo' function in question - in your answer. How does using completely different functions answer the question of why the op is getting errors on 'scrollTo'?

Answer (score 4):

```
/*
* ScrollToElement 1.0
* Copyright (c) 2009 Lauri Huovila, Neovica Oy
*  lauri.huovila@neovica.fi
*  http://www.neovica.fi
*  
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/

(function($) {
    $.scrollToElement = function($element, speed) {

        speed = speed || 750;

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $element.offset().top,
            scrollLeft: $element.offset().left
        }, speed);
        return $element;
    };

    $.fn.scrollTo = function(speed) {
        speed = speed || "normal";
        return $.scrollToElement(this, speed);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#your-div")[0].scrollTo(0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps.

Comment: Sorry, So, First I find the target element that will be affected by the scroll (in this case I used jquery to find the element by Id).

So I use The scrollTo () https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp